# Spark serialization with Kryo fail

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, kryo

**Locally**

I have succesfully launched a spark application locally.
To do that I have start on my machine a spark master and a worker.
I have then execute spark-submit (execution was succesfull).

**Production**

When passing my work on production the same application is lauched in severals machines on AWS and the execution failed.

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.collection.immutable.MapLike$ImmutableDefaultKeySet
```

**Questions**

What is the difference(s) between "Locally" and "Production" ?
Is it possible to simulate the behavior of "Production" on my machine to avoid future crashes ?

Comment: Are you sure you use same version of Spark and Scala in local and production?

Comment: Yes, it is the same :)